# Would every half angle of an angle in each quadrant be in the previous quadrant?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, soft-question

For example, take (5pi)/4 which is in Q3, it's half angle is (5pi)/8 which is in Q2. Is this true for every angle?

Comment: See my comment on that other question.  What about $ \ \frac{\pi}{3} \ $ ?  The short answer is that the "half-angle operation" compresses the principal circle into its first two quadrants, so QI -> QI , QII -> QI , QIII -> QII , QIV -> QII ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Here are two counterexamples:

(7pi)/4 is in the fourth quadrant and (7pi)/8 is in the second quadrant.

(pi)/3 is in the first quadrant and (pi)/6 is also in the first quadrant.